# fatal error: mbedtls/config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino, wifi, aws-iot

I am trying to connect an Arduino UNO WiFi rev 2 with AWS IoT.
For now, I only want to send a random number every 1000ms.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AWS_IOT.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "_____" // SSID of your WIFI
#define WIFI_PASSWD "_____" //your wifi password

#define CLIENT_ID "Tester"// thing unique ID, this id should be unique among all things associated with your AWS account.
#define MQTT_TOPIC "$aws/things/IOT_test/shadow/update" //topic for the MQTT data
#define AWS_HOST "______________________" // your host for uploading data to AWS,

AWS_IOT aws;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initializing thing for AWS");

  Serial.print("Initializing WIFI: Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWD);
  Serial.print("  ");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("\n  Connected.\n  Done");

  Serial.print("\n  Initializing program...");

  Serial.println("\n  Initializing connetction to AWS....");
  if(aws.connect(AWS_HOST, CLIENT_ID) == 0){ // connects to host and returns 0 upon success
    Serial.println("  Connected to AWS\n  Done.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("  Connection failed!\n check for MQTT problems");
  }
  Serial.println("  Done.\n");
}

void loop(){
  // read temperature and humidity
  float number = random(1, 50);

    //create string payload for publishing
    String random_number = "Random number: ";
    random_number += String(number);
    random_number += " %";

    char payload[25];
    random_number.toCharArray(payload, 25);

    Serial.println("Publishing:- ");
    Serial.println(payload);
     if(aws.publish(MQTT_TOPIC, payload) == 0){// publishes payload and returns 0 upon success
      Serial.println("Success\n");
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Failed!\n");
    }
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

I am following a [tutorial for the NodeMCU-ESP32](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y0w977q_yk).

Once I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/jesuschueca/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AWS_IOT/src/network_interface.h:35:0,
                 from /Users/jesuschueca/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AWS_IOT/src/aws_iot_mqtt_client.h:57,
                 from /Users/jesuschueca/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AWS_IOT/src/AWS_IOT.cpp:39:
/Users/jesuschueca/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AWS_IOT/src/network_platform.h:20:10: fatal error: mbedtls/config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mbedtls/config.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compilando para la tarjeta Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2.
```

Any idea on what I could be doing wrong or if the tutorial I am following is not compatible?

Thank you.

Comment: you write sketch for the esp32 Nina module on Uno WiFi? on the main MCU **WiFiNINA library** should be used with Arduino nina firmware in the on-board esp32 module.

Comment: Alright, I should change it to #include <WiFiNINA.h>, correct?

Comment: I changed it and the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to mbedtls 3.0.0.

Under 2.27.0 there is mbedtls/config.h existing under the include directory, but with 3.0.0 it isn't.

I can't compile curl with mbedtls 3.0.0 because of this - but I can compile curl with mbedtls 2.27.0.

Maybe your problem is solved, when you switch to mbedtls 2.27.0.